# Nuxt 3 Router doesn`t detect hash when refresh the page

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I try to add active class in NuxtLinks by url hash, But when refresh the page active class comes to home!
For example the fullpath is /#search and when refresh the page search is not active but home is active, Please help me to resolve this issue.

```js
    <template>
        <nav>
            <NuxtLink v-for="item in menu" :key="item.href" :to="item.href"
                :class="['menu-c--nav--link', {'active': item.href === activeMenuPath}]">
                {{ item.text }}
            </NuxtLink>
        </nav>
    </template>

    <script setup lang="ts">
    import MenuInterface from "@contracts/MenuInterface";

    const menu: MenuInterface[] = [
        {href: '/', text: 'Home'},
        {href: '/#search', text: 'Search'},
        {href: '/#about', text: 'About'},
        {href: '/#certificates', text: 'Certificates'},
        {href: '/#gallery', text: 'Gallery'},
        {href: '/#proposals', text: 'Proposals'},
    ]

    const router = useRouter()
    const activeMenuPath: Ref<string | null> = ref(null)

    watchEffect(() => {
        activeMenuPath.value=router.currentRoute.value.href
    })
    </script>
```